# Swift - Healthkit get highlight string from steps data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit, health-monitoring

So i planned to create some app using swift that use healthkit as our main framework particularly for steps data, but the most data that we will use is highlight that shown as image below **(that string inside red rectangle *"On average, you have walked and run further this month than last month"*)**

[image: that string inside red rectangle]

But i still wondering is that technically possible to get such data or not? cause i'm really stuck on this due limited resources as this topic on the internet

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm also interested

Comment: @Magnus unfortunately not, after talking to few folks who known about such thing, it is an ui that apple provide through the app and not an api base. as a solution myself, i've tried to replicate the health string base on the only number to provide condition to display the string to my app